# What about the epoll_wait returning? Does it sort for the file description for the requested I/O?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, epoll

```
nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);

if (nfds == -1) {
    perror("epoll_pwait");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/*why it traverses the event array from 0 to nfds*/
for (n = 0; n < nfds; ++n) {
      do_use_fd(events[n].data.fd);
}
```

The code is an example of the `epoll` man page, and the `epoll_wait` returns the number of file descriptors ready for the requested I/O  if successful. But I can't know why it will traverse the event array from 0 to nfds. Does the `epoll_wait` sort for the  event array and make the 0 to nfds of the array ready for read or write and other not?

Answer (score 0):

epoll_wait() will fill the first nfds elements of the events array with data about ready fd's. The remaining MAX_EVENTS - nfds elements will not be touched, so they'll contain whatever was there before the call to epoll_wait(). AFAIK there is no particular guaranteed order of the nfds initial elements, whatever ordering there is, is just a coincidence of how the implementation works.